# Where to place an if statement in a component?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a survey-form and want to use an if-statement to print out different results depending on the answers. Right know I have a turnery to print out the answer (that works) but since there is more than two options I want to use an if statement. I am pretty new to this and it would be so helpful to know the best practice on where in the component I can place the if statement.

Thanks!

This is my current code (and the turnery I want to replace is after props.happiness):

```
import React from 'react'

export const Summary = (props) => {

  return (
    <section className="summary">
      <h1>Heres your result!</h1>
        <p>Hello {props.name}</p>
        <p>You are {props.happiness < 3 ? 'so so' : 'Super happy'} with our service</p>
        <p> You choose to do {props.treatment}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Summary = (props) => {
  const renderHappiness = () => {
    if (props.happiness < 3) return 'so so'
    return 'Super happy'
  }

  return (
    <section className="summary">
      <h1>Heres your result!</h1>
        <p>Hello {props.name}</p>
        <p>You are {renderHappiness()} with our service</p>
        <p> You choose to do {props.treatment}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```

This gives you much more freedom to render things while keeping your JSX clean.

Eg. You could use a switch statement in there too if you wanted, like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Summary = (props) => {
  const renderHappiness = () => {
    switch (props.happiness) {
      case 1:
        return 'super sad'
      case 2:
        return 'sad'
      case 3:
        return 'so so'
      case 4:
        return 'happy'
      case 5:
        return 'super happy'
      default:
        return '*unknown*'
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="summary">
      <h1>Heres your result!</h1>
        <p>Hello {props.name}</p>
        <p>You are {renderHappiness()} with our service</p>
        <p> You choose to do {props.treatment}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would abstract it into a function, so you keep your JSX syntax clean:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Summary = (props) => {

  function getHappiness() {
    if (props.happiness < 3) {
      return 'so so';
    } else {
      return 'super happy';
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="summary">
      <h1>Heres your result!</h1>
        <p>Hello {props.name}</p>
        <p>You are {getHappiness()} with our service</p>
        <p> You choose to do {props.treatment}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```